Use of genitive case after a negative
I know to use genitive case after a negative when using the verb to be, but in the example below:

Я не знаю ответа

the word 'answer' seems to be genitive (rather than accusative) after the negative of the verb to know: is this correct?
I don't think the sense is 'I don't have any answer' so an accusative seems more correct.


the word 'answer' seems to be genitive (rather than accusative) after the negative of the verb to know: is this correct?

Yes, that's correct. All transitive verbs accept the genitive after negation.

I know to use genitive case after a negative when using the verb to be

By itself, быть is not a transitive verb in Russian. In the copular sense, it governs the instrumental or, in some cases, the nominative both in affirmative and negative sentences, but never the accusative or the genitive.
It's also used in the proximal construction у меня есть, which is usually translated to English as "I have". In this sense, it does govern the genitive in the negative, but that's a completely different story.

I don't think the sense is 'I don't have any answer' so an accusative seems more correct.

Both can be correct.
By using the accusative, you emphasize the definiteness of the object.
When you say я не знаю ответ, you stress that there is the answer to the question, which you don't know.
But the genitive is always acceptable, when the definiteness is not there or doesn't matter. Even if you're doing a multiple choice test and the question does have the answer, saying я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос is perfectly fine.
